# Facebook log in page in swift

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, authentication

When I try log in in my application with Facebook, I have page in Safari browser with text: You already have authorization PPFF. Or Are you want to have authorization in PPFF?
Also there is the gear on top of the text instead of the application logo. How I can change gear on my logo and type Application name instead of PPFF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been reported earlier and is by design. This dialog will always show up when you start the login flow for a user that is already logged into your app.

You also can't change the appearance of the dialog unfortunately.

You can find the original report here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1024399197610999/

Thanks.